# How to change the applicationId in a Gluon Mobile Project

Tags: android, gluon, gluon-mobile

In order to build different versions of my app, I added the `applicationPackage` property to the build file:

```
jfxmobile {
   javafxportsVersion = '8.60.6'

       android {
            manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
            applicationPackage = 'com.myapp.lite'
       }
}
```

But the generated apk file is still named after the `package` property in the AndroidManifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0.0" >
```

What's the proper way to change the package name if you want to build different flavors of your app like "Lite" and "Full" ?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, when you use the Gluon plugin to create a Mobile project, the jfxmobile plugin builds the default `AndroidManifest.xml` file, based on your input (main class, package name). After that, any modification you make on your project (like refactoring the main class name or the package name) *won't be updated* on the Android manifest file, so you have to do it manually yourself.

If you have a look at the [source code](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/javafxmobile-plugin/src/tip/src/main/groovy/org/javafxports/jfxmobile/plugin/android/task/ValidateManifest.groovy?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#ValidateManifest.groovy-21) of the plugin, there is a way to force recreating the manifest every time you run the `android` task: Just delete the file under src/android/AndroidManifest.xml, and remove the `manifest` property in the build.gradle file. When you run `android` or `androidIntall`, a new *default* Android manifest will be created under `build/javafxports/tmp/android`, taking into account your `applicationPackage` property.

Notice this won't allow any custom change in the manifest, like adding or removing permissions or changing the version numbers. So clearly it is not a complete solution.

Another approach will be creating a custom task that recreates the AndroidManifest file based on your own settings, based on the way the plugin does it itself.

You can file an issue under javafxports [repo](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/javafxmobile-plugin/issues?status=new&status=open) if you think a more dynamic solution is required to build the apk. For instance, allowing the use of the same approach as in Android, where a `strings.xml` file is used to set some metadata (@string).

Comment: Once again very interessting. I was assuming that the `androidApplication` property is working like `defaultConfig {applicationId "com.myApp.lite"}`.   You have been a great source of help on the way to my first play store release, which in turn would not have been possible without the Gluon framework. Many thanks for all your help